# How to get current firewall's check_path?

Tags: symfony

**Question: How to get the `form_login.check_path` by given firewall name?**

We subscribe to `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvent::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` in order to log successful logins inside an Application that has multiple firewalls.

One firewall uses JWT tokens via Guard authentication which has the negative effect that this event is triggered for **every request** with a valid token.

We have currently solved this by manually checking whether the current route matches the firewall's check-path and stopping the event-propagation together with an early return otherwise.

As we're adding more firewalls (with different tokens) I'd like to solve this more generally. Therefore I want to check whether the current route matches the current firewalls check-path **without** hardcoding any route or firewall-name.

There is a class to generate **Logout URLs** for the current firewall used by Twig `logout_path()` method which gets the logout route/path from the firewall listeners somehow.  (`Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutUrlGenerator`)

Before I hop into a long debugging session I thought maybe someone has solved this case before ;)

Any ideas?

Example code:

```
class UserEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    /** @var FirewallMapInterface|FirewallMap */
    protected $firewallMap;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, FirewallMapInterface $firewallMap)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->firewallMap = $firewallMap;
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $firewallName = $this->firewallMap->getFirewallConfig($request)->getName();
        $routeName = $request->get('_route');

        if (('firewall_jwt' === $firewallName) && ('firewall_jwt_login_check' !== $routeName)) {
            $event->stopPropagation();
            return;
        }

        $this->logger->info(
            'A User has logged in interactively.',
            array(
                'event' => SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN,
                'user' => $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser()->getUuid(),
        ));
```

Comment: Are you using a Symfony version < 3.3 ? Otherwise, try with JSON authentication instead of Guard, which should allow to restrict authentication to a given `check_path` only, then the [job is done](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4427cf9157d5d896e2221a31afeac293f2ad9971/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordJsonAuthenticationListener.php#L84-L86)! [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html).

Comment: @yceruto I'm aware of JSON auth but the problem is that  login (`form_login`/`json_login`) and the authentication process itself are two different processes. For JWT tokens to work you need either guard or a custom auth provider. The firewall that triggers `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` doesn't even have a `form_login` option set but still triggers these events whenever guard authentication succeeds. We're using a second firewall that allows anonymous access only for the login/register/logout/password-reset routes. Do you understand?

Comment: Yep, I do. You might need do it manually so, i.e. inject this configuration to the subscriber. See an idea in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check_path` option is only available from authentication factory/listener, so you could pass this configuration manually to the subscriber class while the container is building.

This solution take account that `check_path` could be a route name or path, that's why `HttpUtils` service is injected too:

```
namespace AppBundle\Subscriber;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\FirewallMapInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

class UserEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $logger;
    private $httpUtils;
    private $firewallMap;
    private $checkPathsPerFirewall;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, HttpUtils $httpUtils, FirewallMapInterface $firewallMap, array $checkPathsPerFirewall)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->httpUtils = $httpUtils;
        $this->firewallMap = $firewallMap;
        $this->checkPathsPerFirewall = $checkPathsPerFirewall;
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $firewallName = $this->firewallMap->getFirewallConfig($request)->getName();
        $checkPath = $this->checkPathsPerFirewall[$firewallName];

        if (!$this->httpUtils->checkRequestPath($request, $checkPath)) {
            $event->stopPropagation();

            return;
        }

        $this->logger->info('A User has logged in interactively.', array(
            'event' => SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN,
            'user' => $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser()->getUsername(),
        ));
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onInteractiveLogin'];
    }
}
```

After regiter this subscriber as service (`AppBundle\Subscriber\UserEventSubscriber`) we need implement `PrependExtensionInterface` in your DI extension to be able to access the security configuration and complete the subscriber definition with the check paths per firewall:

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use AppBundle\Subscriber\UserEventSubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;

class AppExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    // ...

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $checkPathsPerFirewall = [];

        $securityConfig = $container->getExtensionConfig('security');
        foreach ($securityConfig[0]['firewalls'] as $name => $config) {
            if (isset($config['security']) && false === $config['security']) {
                continue; // skip firewalls without security
            }

            $checkPathsPerFirewall[$name] = isset($config['form_login']['check_path'])
                ? $config['form_login']['check_path']
                : '/login_check'; // default one in Symfony
        }

        $subscriber = $container->getDefinition(UserEventSubscriber::class);
        $subscriber->setArgument(3, $checkPathsPerFirewall);
    }
}
```

I hope it fits your need.

Comment: Hm I was thinking about getting the config in a DI extension before ... that actually feels somewhat like a dirty solution to me. I thought there was an easier way to get the route/path directly. from a RequestMatcher / Security Listener. Anyways I'll give your solution a shot and get back to you soon. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

for PHP8

In __construct :

> ```
> public function __construct(
>     private RequestStack    $requestStack,
>     private FirewallMapInterface $firewallMap
> )
> {
> }
> ```

use this :

> ```
>     $firewallName = $this->firewallMap->getFirewallConfig($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest())->getName();
> ```